# DDL trigger - can't disable the trigger

Tags: database, oracle, triggers

I "accidentaly" created a trigger that will not allow anyone to perform DDL on database. Now I can't do anything with my database. Not even sysdba can drop this trigger. I tried disabling it, but still, it triggers before doing so. Here is the evil trigger I enabled:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Prevent_Changes
BEFORE DDL ON DATABASE
  BEGIN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (
      num => -20000,
      msg => 'ERROR, no changes to database allowed!');
  END;
```

Comment: Wild guess. `DBMS_UTILITY.INVALIDATE(trigger_object_id)` then `DROP TRIGGER Prevent_Changes`.

Comment: Another wild guess. Did you try to modify code removing that exception? Like put null instead or smth... Maybe after this you will be able to drop or disable it.

Comment: @Art Yep, worked. Can you please put your answer into the aswers section? So I can mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: That's OK, I'm glad it worked, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just edit the trigger first. Remove this part.

```
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (
      num => -20000,
      msg => 'ERROR, no changes to database allowed!');
```

You may just add:

```
dbms_output.put_line('fine');
```

This will stop raising the exception on your any ddl. It should work.